Angular Init two services that depends on each other
I have Database service that reads data from IndexedDB using RxDB library and has initDatabase function to initialize it.
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DatabaseService {
  private static database: MyDatabase;

  constructor() {}

  async initDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Initializing database');
    if (!DatabaseService.database) {
      const db = await createRxDatabase<MyDatabaseCollections>({
        name: 'mydb',
        storage: getRxStorageDexie(),
      });

      await db.addCollections({
        items: {
          schema: itemSchema,
        },
        baseUnits: {
          schema: baseUnitSchema,
        },
        brands: {
          schema: brandSchema,
        },
        contacts: {
          schema: contactSchema,
        },
        suppliers: {
          schema: SupplierSchema,
        },
      });

      DatabaseService.database = db;
    }
  }

  getDatabase(): MyDatabase {
    if (!DatabaseService.database) {
      throw new Error('Database not initialized yet');
    }
    return DatabaseService.database;
  }
}

And Items service that depends on the Database service by initItemsService function
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ItemsService {
  private itemsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<ItemType[]>([]);
  private itemSearchTermSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  public items$;
  public searchTerm$;

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {
    this.items$ = this.itemsSubject.asObservable();
    this.searchTerm$ = this.itemSearchTermSubject.asObservable();
  }

  setItems(items: ItemType[]) {
    this.itemsSubject.next(items);
  }

  getItems(): ItemType[] {
    return this.itemsSubject.getValue();
  }

  setItemSearchTerm(term: string) {
    this.itemSearchTermSubject.next(term);
  }

  getItemSearchTerm(): string {
    return this.itemSearchTermSubject.getValue();
  }

  findItemsByName(name: string): ItemType[] {
    return this.itemsSubject
      .getValue()
      .filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()));
  }

  initItemsService() {
    this.databaseService
      .getDatabase()
      .items.find()
      .$.subscribe((docs) => {
        this.setItems(docs);
      });
  }
}

Finally initializing both services inside app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    MessageService,
    DatabaseService,
    provideAppInitializer(() => inject(DatabaseService).initDatabase()),
    provideAppInitializer(() => inject(ItemsService).initItemsService()),
  ],
};

But the database is not yet initialized by the time Item reads it getting error:

Database not initialized yet

Which is the error in funcrion getDatabase()

If both the initializers fire at the same time, the database might not be initialized when the second initializer accesses it.

Could you try using then on the promise returned from the first initializer to call the service method.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimations(),
    MessageService,
    DatabaseService,
    provideAppInitializer(() => {
      const itemService: ItemService = inject(ItemsService);
      return inject(DatabaseService).initDatabase().then(() => {
        itemService.initItemsService();
      });
    }),
  ],
};


Is there a reason you first inject the ItemService instead of provideAppInitializer(() => inject(DatabaseService).initDatabase().then(() => { inject(ItemsService).initItemsService(); }))?

@jabaa I havent used provideAppInitializer, I just added it for safety, since I was not sure if inject will work inside the then block, if it works like with your code, then go for that itself
